# Cant change some characters in colnames with gsub, such as, '?', '+','('

Tags: r

I have imported a csv file with 'weird' symbols. Below I have reproduced and example. Im able to change only some characters with gsub. It doesnt work for '?', '(' and '+'. How can I change/remove them? Thanks!

```
x <- c("Aryl Sulfat/m,+", "4/3-(3_hydroxy) acid", "2- 2acid, 4- acid", "1-acetamido-2-/ sulfate", "acid?")
a <- 1:2
b<- 6:7
c <- 5:6
d <- 8:9
e <- 3:4
d<- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
colnames(d) <- x
d
  Aryl Sulfat/m,+ 4/3-(3_hydroxy) acid 2- 2acid, 4- acid 1-acetamido-2-/ sulfate acid?
1               1                    6                 5                       8     3
2               2                    7                 6                       9     4

colnames(d) <- gsub("?", "", colnames(d)) #doesnt work
colnames(d) <- gsub("-", "", colnames(d))
colnames(d) <- gsub("/", "", colnames(d))
colnames(d) <- gsub("(", "", colnames(d)) #doesnt work
colnames(d) <- gsub(")", "", colnames(d))
colnames(d) <- gsub(",", "", colnames(d))
colnames(d) <- gsub("+", "", colnames(d)) #doesnt work

  Aryl Sulfatm+ 43(3_hydroxy acid 2 2acid 4 acid 1acetamido2 sulfate acid?
1             1                 6              5                   8     3
2             2                 7              6                   9     4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work it's because those are special characters that you would use inside a regex. You would need to backslashed them.

```r
gsub("\\?", "", colnames(d))
gsub("\\(", "", colnames(d))
gsub("\\+", "", colnames(d))
```

---

Anyway, for your case I would suggest you to use something like this.
Keep only numbers, letters and underscores:

```r
gsub("[^[:alnum:]^_]", "", colnames(d))
#> [1] "ArylSulfatm"        "433_hydroxyacid"    "22acid4acid"        "1acetamido2sulfate" "acid"
```